# What does the idiom "Putting the pedal to the metal" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms, idioms-in-context

Please help me figure out the meaning of the idiom "putting the pedal to the metal" in the following sentence from the description of the game "KartRider Rush+" (not available online):

***Putting the pedal to the metal*** and being very adorable while doing so, the game drifts onto the App Store with an amazing makeover.

The lexical meanings of the said idiom are "to drive as fast as possible" or "do something with maximum speed and effort." I am not sure which of them fits here.

Here is a description of the game from a different source:

*The kart racing sensation enjoyed by over 300M players worldwide is back and better than ever with more style, more game modes, more thrill! Race with friends or just play it solo through a variety of gameplay modes.*

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Both meanings fit.  That was probably the intention.

Comment: Here I take it to mean intensity rather than effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting use case of this idiomatic expression because it's in a context where the idiom could actually apply literally (for comedic effect).

In general, the definitions you provided for the expression are accurate.  In this case, the "maximum... effort" meaning, but the joke is that the phrase is used when actually talking about racing cars.

Most specifically, the expression is referring to the "amazing makeover", describing how the developers of the mobile game have updated or improved it in some significant way.